# Total Commander - Show context menu immediately (mouse+key shortcut)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, context-menu, total-commander

I absolutely hate "shortcuts" with a delay. So I'm looking for method how to view context menu immediately in TC using a mouse in my right hand (left is laying on keyboard).

Known methods (and why I don't like them)

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>F10</kbd> (two hand shortcut)
- <kbd>Menu Key</kbd> (not in reach of my left hand, also not available on my laptop)
- Use Windows standard selection mode (in this mode every <kbd>LMB</kbd> click resets selection)
  [image]
- Custom shortcut reachable by left hand (for example <kbd>LALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> works fine, but I'd like mouse + keyboard shortcut)

I'm OK with some {<kbd>LALT</kbd>,<kbd>LCTRL</kbd>, ...} + <kbd>RMB</kbd> too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no delay whith this option:

[image]

Otherwise, there is no option to achieve that, AFAIK.
So to open the context menu with the mouse click, 3d party app like Autohotkey can be used.
For example, in TC assign a shortcut Ctrl+Space for the "cm_ContextMenu" command.
Then use AHK script for Ctrl+RightClick:

```
#If winActive("ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD") 

^rbutton::
    send ^{space}
return
```

Comment: This is exactly what I describe in my list (item 3). It "breaks" selections.

Comment: @Lluser Ok, fair enough. Then I think there is no option, and only Autohotkey can help, I added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define custom-shortcuts in TC that combine with the mouse-buttons.
That functionality is simply not available.

Best you can do is a left-hand only short-cut (as you already discovered) or use a third-party tool (e.g. AutoHotKey or something similar) that makes right-mouse + some key under the left-hand invoke Shift-F10.